# Physical Storage of InMemory Cache of Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server, state-management

According to Apollo Client docs, the InMemory cache is used in the apollo client cache as instantiated in the below code

```
import { InMemoryCache, ApolloClient } from '@apollo/client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  // ...other arguments...
  cache: new InMemoryCache(options)
});
```

Reference: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/

1. Where is this in-memory storage physically created? Is it in sessionStorage or localStorage or indexed db or front-end servers?
2. What is the lifecycle of stored data inside this cache?is it deleted on closure of browser session like session cookies or tab closure like session storage?

Comment: Apollo-client is open source. Look at https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/tree/main/src/cache

Answer (score 1):

InMemory Cache exists as a field of Apollo Client, so it shares the same lifecycle. This also means that each browser tab has its own InMemory cache, and the cache exists no longer than the tab itself.

If you want to share the cache across multiple tabs, you can use the "apollo3-cache-persist" library. This library is designed to synchronize InMemory Cache across different tabs using storage such as sessionStorage or localStorage.

Related links:

- [source code of internal storage for InMemory cache](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/main/src/cache/inmemory/entityStore.ts#L658)
- [how to use "apollo3-cache-persist" library](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cache-persist/?tab=readme-ov-file#web)
- [list of persist storages supported by "apollo3-cache-persist"](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cache-persist/blob/master/docs/storage-providers.md)